# Make element scroll slower (Parallax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an element on my page absolutely positioned.

Im trying to write a snippet of jQuery to make that element scroll at a slower rate than the rest of the elements on the page.

I've written this so far but cannot seem to get it too work at all. Has anybody experience with this and if so would you care explaining?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $window = $(window);
    $('.twit-bird').css({
        'top' : -($('window')/3)+"px"
     });
});
```

---

I've also tried to add an anchor, a fixed div at the top of my window to work out the calcs from that with no luck...

---

also tried this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Cache the Window object
 windowScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

 $(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.twit-bird').css({
        'top' : -(windowScroll/3)+"px"
    });
 });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can point you in the right direction. You need your `$('.twit-bird').css()` to get called every time the window is scrolled. Also you forgot `.scrollTop()`, and don't quote `window` (or, even better just use `this`) ...

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 

   $('.twit-bird').css({
      'top' : -($(this).scrollTop()/3)+"px"
   }); 

});
```

Comment: I've added my latest code with those amends, works on intial scroll but doesnt keep calculating as scroll continues...

Comment: @Timothy Aaron - You script look perfect in Firefox, but it is very jumpy in Chrome - espcially if the top value is not negative - do you think there is a solution to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.richardshepherd.com/smashing/parallax/background.html) is a very very good tutorial for parallax scrolling. It made me understanding how it really works.