# Background while scrolling?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have demo one from this address: [here](http://skydrive.com)
When page scroll down, background will be obscured gradually by under element. You can check demo.

[image]
[image]

I want to know the technique they use or say me how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: same thread you can look at parrallax here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235568/make-element-scroll-slower-parrallax

Comment: Thanks Harish much :)

Answer (score 1):

Its known as parallax scrolling.

Here are few [DEMOS](http://www.awwwards.com/20-best-websites-with-parallax-scrolling-of-2013.html) for it.

You can use parallax js for doing it.

[Click here for parallax js](http://wagerfield.github.io/parallax/)